# period.apply in xts returning more than 1 value

Tags: r, time-series, xts, zoo

I have an `xts` object and I am trying to use `period.apply` with a function that would return more than one value for each non-overlapping period.  For example: I run a regression and would like to return the residuals for each non-overlapping period and thus my function returns all the dates from that period along with the residual at each particular date.  It currently seems that `xts` does not support this behavior.  Is this correct? Is there a work around?

```
> df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(31)+10, y=rnorm(31)+10)
> xts.data <- xts(df, order.by=as.Date(13514:(13544),origin="1970-01-01"))
> f <- function(d) {as.numeric(coredata(d[,"x"]))}
> period.apply(xts.data, INDEX=endpoints(xts.data,"weeks"), FUN=f)
Error in coredata.xts(x) : currently unsupported data type
```

Comment: reproducible code please

Comment: Incorrect. xts has supported this for awhile. Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: It's not reproducible because you don't tell us what `df` is.  Plus, `df` is a function in the stats package, so your code causes an error.

Comment: oops sorry about that! adding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It just occurred to me that the problem is likely that each non-overlapping period doesn't have the same number of observations, so there's no way to easily create a matrix-like structure.

Use something like this instead, and notice how each list element isn't the same length:

```
lapply(split(xts.data,"weeks"), f)
```

To illustrate how `period.apply` can return more than one column per period:

```
period.apply(xts.data, endpoints(xts.data,"weeks"), range)
period.apply(xts.data, endpoints(xts.data,"weeks"), colMeans)
```

Comment: could you explain why that should matter? wouldn't the constaint be that each return value has to have the same number of columns? rows can vary?

Comment: @Alex: `period.apply` only returns one row per period.  The function you pass to `period.apply` must return a vector.

Comment: i think that's basically the answer to the question then no? one cannot pass functions that return vectors to `period.apply`

Comment: @Alex: no, the function **can** return a vector, but it must always be the same length for all time periods.

Comment: it would be *most useful* if, like sapply, period.apply were to resort to a list output when it gets a complex or irregular data structure back that it cannot turn into an xts or a matrix, as I run into this problem all the time.

Comment: @ThomasBrowne: it would be most useful if you could submit a patch, or at least a reproducible example of the desired cases and behavior, rather that providing a vague description and expecting package authors/maintainers to do all the hard work.